# Android NDK SDL Deprecated

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sdl, deprecated

I installed the NDK with SDL.

I am using Windows 7 with MinGW.

When I compile the source in Android Studio I get the warning:
`[deprecation] AbsoluteLayout in android.widget has been deprecated`

I get this warning 4 times from the file:
`/jni/SDL/android-project/src/org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity.java`

I also get these warnings:

```
[deprecation] CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO in AudioFormat has been deprecated
[deprecation] CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO in AudioFormat has been deprecated
[deprecation] SURFACE_TYPE_GPU in SurfaceHolder has been deprecated
[deprecation] setType(int) in SurfaceHolder has been deprecated
[deprecation] LA_88 in PixelFormat has been deprecated
[deprecation] RGBA_4444 in PixelFormat has been deprecated
[deprecation] RGBA_5551 in PixelFormat has been deprecated
[deprecation] RGB_332 in PixelFormat has been deprecated
[deprecation] ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK in MotionEvent has been deprecated
[deprecation] ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT in MotionEvent has been deprecated
```

I installed SDL using Mercurial:
`hg clone http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL`
And followed the steps in `README-android.txt`

Have I installed something incorrectly? Is SDL no longer supported? How can I fix these warnings?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential to your app—never because you simply prefer to program in C/C++`

Comment: In this instance it is essential to my app. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but I do not believe that SDL has ever been officially supported by Google.  The fact that you're hitting deprecation warnings shouldn't be particularly troublesome, however you may have to upgrade your version of SDL at some point in the future to take advantage of the newer APIs if/when the SDL team gets around to it.